# How do I toggle my modal overlay off?

Tags: jquery, overlay, toggle, eventtrigger

I am using jQuery tools to trigger an overlay on a checkbox 'change' event. Unfortunately, the overlay gets triggered whether I toggle the checkbox on or off.

*Click on the **dedicated hosting option*** on the live Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/amit_e/dMxea/3/

I only want the overlay fired when the checkbox is checked on and DO NOT want the overlay event firing if the checkbox is off. **How do I do that?**

Comment: The problem is that the checkbox never get the status "checked", cause of any reasons the `$this.overlay()` command inhibits the change of checked status.

Comment: @Armin You're right. How do I fix this?

Comment: I have no idea! Sorry. I don't know (and like) this flowplayer tools framework.

Comment: any overlay modal that you could suggest for my needs?

Answer (score 1):

i have updated the code , the problem was of the overlay function

Check the solution in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dMxea/6/

Comment: I like this but would want the overlay to work instead of just showing and hiding. If I try firing the overlay with your code, I am back to square one.

Comment: so how ur expecting the overlay to be ?

Comment: I just want a normal overlay to fire, @Akhil